# Отображение браузера в omxplayer (OpenMAX) на RaspberryPi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

Заранее приношу извинения, если вопрос покажется непрофессиональным. Столкнулся с задачей управляемого вывода видеопотока через hdmi посредством RaspberryPi. В качестве инструмента использую openmax, в качестве языка программирования - Python. Для управления использую subprocess.Popen, открывая omxplayer с необходимыми параметрами и управляя плеером через команды в пайп. Задача, которая вызвала сложности - пускать дополнительным слоем поверх проигрываемого видео html-страницу. По факту - еще один видеопоток, который бы транслировал рендер html-файла. В каком направлении мыслить? Существует ли возможность каким-то образом превратить вывод программы (например web-браузера) в видеопоток? Возможно это будет RTSP, или еще что-то, что можно использовать в качестве источника для отображения в omxplayer.

Comment: если забыть о том *как* вы это сейчас пытаетесь реализовать, можно ли упомянуть *что* вы пытаетесь сделать (с точки зрения конечного результата)—[какой контекст](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044)

Comment: Мне необходимо поверх видео наложить HTML-страницу и упаковать все это в выводимый через hdmi видеопоток

Comment: это уже написано у вас в вопросе. Это описывает *как* вы пытаетесь что-то сделать. Контекст мог бы позволить возможно лучшее решение предложить.

Comment: Собственно задача - подключать к любым устройствам, имеющим hdmi порт, Raspberry. И с помощью неё воспроизводить видео. Работа через openmax необходима для железного ускорения, т.к. видео будет HD. Поверх будет достаточно сложный по верстке шаблон, в него будет вставлено множество динамических данных (х-ки устройства), поэтому идея с вёрсткой на веб мне кажется самой удобной.

Comment: я бы попробовал покопать в сторону включения аппаратного ускорения  в браузере (`chrome://gpu`)  для html5 video (тогда легко наложить другой html поверх)—не знаю возможно ли это сейчас. Альтернатива: screencasting как видео-поток с другой машины, кажется слишком усложнённой.